# Wordpress 500 Internal Server Error - No Scripts / Styles get loaded

Tags: php, wordpress

So I bought a webhosting package and my domain, set up wordpress like I did many times before but unfortunatly from the beginning (installation, login, backend, frontend) many files dont get loaded.

The errors look like this:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) example.com/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=3.9.2
```

The files are there but this error shows up...

I already checked chmod (Folders are 755, Files 644) so nothing special

Does somebody know how to fix this problem?

The error logfile says:

```
Premature end of script headers:
```

EDIT:

Problem solved. It seems that I need to install WP in the root not in cgi-bin.

Comment: Do you have access to the error logs? or ask your web hosting to receive it.

Comment: If you'reseeing server errors on things that should be straightforward, like CSS files as in your example, that suggests a possible problem with .htaccess.

Comment: Ok because there is no .htaccess in the root. Only outside somewhere in cgi-data and it only says "deny from all"...

Comment: I deleted Wordpress from my Server, deleted all DB Tables from Wordpress and reuploaded it. After calling the install.php it still looks the same (no styles just a white background with the html form) and 7 Errors like above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check all wordpress required files have been installed on the server.  If this is a new site, try installing wordpress again.